# Retrieve fully populated dynamic content with PhantomJS

Tags: javascript, web-scraping, phantomjs

I downloaded pjscrape (running PhantomJS under the hood), and in fact, page queries returned fully populated content, including dynamic content.  Unfortunately, pjscrape only emits JSON or CSV.  I need HTML.

Using PhantomJS alone, I have this script (call is my-query.js):

```
var page = require('webpage').create();
page.open('http://www.sonoma.edu/calendar/groups/clubs.html', function (status) {
    console.log("status: " + status);
    if (status !== "success") {
      console.log("Unable to access network");
    } else {
      page.includeJs("http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js", function() {
          console.log("Got jQuery...");
          var fullyPopulatedContent = null;
          page.evaluate(function() {
              $(document).ready(function() {
                  fullyPopulatedContent = $("html").html();
                });
          });
          window.setTimeout(function() {
              console.log(fullyPopulatedContent);
            }, 10000);
      });
    }
  });
```

But this logic never sets `fullyPopulatedContent` after the `page.evaluate` is done.  IE, `fullyPopulatedContent` is just always `null`.

This seems like such a trivial application that you would think PhantomJS would do it out of the box for free.

Any clues how to make such queries work, when the target URL comprises content dynamically populated via Ajax/javascript or frames?  And if frames are involved, can you also please explain how PhantomJS navigates through frame content, as the online documentation and examples are not clear on that topic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PhantomJS has two contexts. `page.evaluate()` is the only function that provides access to the DOM/page context. The function is sandboxed which is why you would need to explicitly pass data in and out.

Another problem is that the event that `$(...).ready()` listens on was probably triggered long before you call `$.ready()` inside of `page.evaluate()`. If that is the only reason why you wanted to load jQuery, then you shouldn't do it.

You could simply wait a static amount of time:

```
var page = require('webpage').create();
page.open('http://www.sonoma.edu/calendar/groups/clubs.html', function (status) {
    console.log("status: " + status);
    if (status !== "success") {
      console.log("Unable to access network");
    } else {
        window.setTimeout(function() {
            console.log(page.content);
            phantom.exit();
        }, 10000); // adjust time for every page
    }
});
```

The problem is of course, you cannot easily determine whether the page is fully loaded. A generally good approach is to [`waitFor`](https://github.com/ariya/phantomjs/blob/master/examples/waitfor.js) (function from the examples) a specific condition like a final element appears or at least x elements of the same type are present in the page. This is usually done with CSS selectors using `document.querySelector()` through `page.evaluate()`.

Another way would be to count requested resources and finished resources to see when there aren't any pending requests for a small amount of time and hope that the time between resource requests is appropriately selected.

**Frames:**

PhantomJS automatically fetches (i)frames as part of the page load. Though, they may finish loading later than the main/parent frame. That's why you might need an additional waiting period.

When you take a screenshot with `page.render()` you will see the complete page including the loaded (or currently loading) frames.

Since frames are separate documents which have their own document root, PhantomJS doesn't include them when you try to print the page source of the main/parent page with `page.content`. You first need to change into their context in order to print their DOM representation.

You can either do that by name (if the frame has a name) or by index (depending on the number of frames in the current (parent) frame). Use [`page.switchToFrame()`](http://phantomjs.org/api/webpage/method/switch-to-frame.html) for that. Then you can retrieve the frame content with `page.frameContent`. Since you switched into the frame context, now you can do all interaction that you could previously do in the main frame like freely changing the DOM or clicking on stuff. When you're done with the frame, then you can change back with `page.switchToParentFrame()`.

Comment: I tried several timeouts.  In *all* cases, the page queried never was fully populated with dynamic content.  I got the HTML body of the URL in question -- without the dynamic content.  Are you about your listed code?

Comment: Is it possible that PhantomJS does not handle dynamic content populated through the iframe element?

Comment: Of course it does, but you have to switch to the childFrame before you can access its DOM or use `page.frameContent` after switching. iFrame content will not be visible from the parent/main frame.

Comment: Neither PhantomJS examples nor online documentations is very clear on navigating through frame content.  Can you please clear up how that is done?  Thx.

Comment: Sure, when you clarify that in your question. What information are you interested in? What kind of interactions are you interested in?

Comment: I've added the frame description.